# MongoDB - Compare the field value with array size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to return all documents which satisfy `document.field.value > document.array.length`. I'm trying to do this using MongoClient in ExpressJS and was not able to find answers on SO.

Here is what I have tried but this gives an empty list.

```js
const db = ref()
const c = db.collection(t)
const docs = await c.find({ 
                "stop.time":{$gt: new Date().toISOString()},
                "stop.expect": {$gt: { $size: "stop.riders"}}
            })
console.log(docs)
```

Also tried replacing

```
"stop.expect": {$gt: { $size: "stop.riders"}}
```

with the below code which does not compile

```
$expr: {$lt: [{$size: "stop.riders"}, "stop.expect"]}
```

Sample data:

```
{ "stop": { "expect":3, "riders": ["asd", "erw", "wer"] } },
{ "stop": { "expect":4, "riders": ["asq", "frw", "wbr"] } }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for debugging purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun added data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter the query with a complex query involving the calculation, you need to use the [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator, which allows the aggregation operators.

Next, within the `$expr` operator, to refer to the field, you need to add the prefix `$`.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      {
        $size: "$stop.riders"
      },
      "$stop.expect"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xRq7aKhQ03g)

Comment: Why is the $ not needed for "stop.time"

Comment: Okay, I think I need to further explain it. Let's say if you want to filter a document by the field with parsed in value, you refer to that field without needing the `$` `{ "stop.time": /* VALUE */ }`. However, sometimes when we want to find the document with complex query (like calculation with referring to another field), we need to use the [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator which is an aggregate operator that allows referring other fields. Within the `$expr` operator, referring to the field requires a prefix `$`.

Answer (score 0):

To compare fields within a document to each other, you must use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/). It would look like this:

```js
const docs = await c.find({ 
  $expr: { $gt: ["$stop.expect", { $size: "$stop.riders" }] },
});
```

I omitted the `stop.time` condition because it's not in your sample data and it's unclear what type of field it is, if it actually is in your data (whether it's a Date or String would be very important).

Note that this sort of query is unable to use an index.